# mvc 4 simpleroleprovider loose ApplicationName after Login

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating an application with VS10 ASP.NET MVC4 .NET Framework 4. I used VS10 supplied model for WEB ASP.NET MVC 4 application. After creation, without any change to the applied model, I used the ASP.net Administration tool to create members and roles and everything went fine. I intended to use

> Roles.IsUserInRole

function to taylor views for specific user groups. But after sign in, the function doesn't work nor works

> Authorize(Roles:="rolename")

applied to a specific function in a controller. The cause: I verified that ApplicatioName was lost after each testuser signed in (I don't know how: no change to source had yet been made) and SimpleRoleProvider doesn't permit to modify programmatically the current ApplicationName value (a specific exception is raised). Is it possible to overcome this problem without changing Role Provider?

Comment: What exception is being raised?

Comment: The exception raised is: Specified method is not supported

Comment: Can you show your code where you initialize simple membership? also say where it is in your structure. By default there is an attribute decorating accounts controller but it should be moved over to global.asax.

Comment: The code that initialize simple membership is placed in folder "Filters" and it is the standard code supplied with model. I'm unable to supply the whole code

Comment: That is your problem. I will post a wee solution.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, MVC4 simple membership is not set up correctly. I detailed  this on a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666116/initializesimplemembership-filter-issue/16666740#16666740)

What you essentially need to do is

1) Remove the file under the filters folder.

2) Initialize SimpleMembership on application_start(). Best place is in AuthConfig file which is called by global.asax

3) Remove the initialize simple membership attribute from account controller

If you look at the accepted solution in the above link I give a little more detail if you need it.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll try soon and shall report you for results

Comment: I tried the solution you suggest, but when I applied the simple changes, taking autocreatetable = True in my situation, I obtain the exception "Impossible to open required database. Access not succeeded...". Using original source, with InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute, the problem doesn't appear. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: I modified slightly your suggestion, applying change after SimpleMembeshipProvider start up, at the end of global.asax. The situation changed in the sense that ApplicationName is lost immediately. So I think this may depend from machine.config. Is it possible or you have better ideas? thanks

Comment: I concluded that there is no solution and proceeded disabling SimpleMembership. This required some change in standard template, because WebMatrix cannot be used anymore, but it wasn't a hard work

Comment: I dont think simplemembership was at fault, ive used it across a few MVC projects without this error. I concluded something was edited elsewhere and couldn't offer much assistance as I didnt know what. Glad you got passed the prob tho!

Comment: Thanks anyway for your support. Also your indication about a specific my machine condition is useful. I hope to be able to precise it, when I'll have some time availability. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I think to have found an explanation to my problem. In MSDN, in the chapter regarding ApplicationName property in SimpleMembershipProvider class I found this note:

> If the SimpleMembershipProvider class has been initialized using a call to the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection method, this property is not supported and will throw a NotSupportedException exception. However, if the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection method has not been called, and if you have configured your site to use the standard ASP.NET membership provider, this property is passed through to the standard membership provider. For more information, see the SimpleMembershipProvider class overview.

Initially it was not clear for me. But after many tests, I think to have undestood. SimpleMemebrshipProvider has a powerful but resticted goal and its implementation in Account Controller in MVC 4 Template is an example. It doesn't take care of ApplicationName, because it ovverrides this necessity, but, with this behavior, it limits the access to functions of "Roles" that require ApplicationName set.
To confirm my hypothesis and the undestanding of the note, I removed :

```
<InitializeSimpleMembership()>
```

from Account Controller. Everything went OK and I was able to use all the functions I need. I had to change something in the controller, because I couldn't use WebMatrix anymore, but the changes were not so hard.
If anybody has any comment about my conclusions, he/she will be wellcome